# static files not found error in django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I know that this problem has already been asked several times here. I have searched and read a number of answers but no help. I guess, I am missing something very basic.

In my settings.py, I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = join(APPS_DIR, "static/")
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [join(APPS_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = join(APPS_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

In my config/urls.py, I have:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have a file located at `/static/core/js/jquery_countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js` which I am trying to load in template as below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'core/js/jquery_countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js' %}"> </script>
```

The top of the same template looks like

```
{% extends "contest/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
```

This results in following server error:

```
[23/Mar/2018 10:12:08] "GET /static/core/js/jquery_countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1858
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create folder **static_files** in your app directory. And place all your static files inside it. Then use the following settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = join(APPS_DIR, "static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [join(APPS_DIR, 'static_files')]
```

If it does not solve your issue, then run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`. It will copy all the static files (Not only from your app but also from django admin, third party apps etc) to the **STATIC_ROOT** folder.

**Details**

For local serving, django server will look in to the `STATICFILES_DIRS`. So you dont need to run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command. All the external apps may have STATICFILES_DIRS  where they place their static files. For production server you need to collect all these static files scattered around all your apps in to a single place. Thats what `python manage.py collectstatic` command will do. It will copy all the static files in to `STATIC_ROOT` directory

Comment: Just to clarify, the file I used to load is located in static_files directory, However, the server shows it to be in static directory. Why is it so?

Comment: for local serving, django server will look in to the STATICFILES_DIRS. So you dont need to run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command. All the external apps may have STATICFILES_DIRS  where the place there static files

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Not only did you solve my problem but also cleared some doubts. :)

Comment: Always welcome. Answer updated base on your comment. Please do refer

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for static files in app directories only but have your file in global static files. You should use the commented STATICFILES_DIRS setting to specify all places to search for static files.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Uncommenting the same line  gives me an error The `STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting`

Comment: Checkout the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs. Also, ``STATIC_ROOT`` is normally for where you will deploy static files in production (when you run ``python manage.py collectstatic``).

Comment: Thanks, commenting out the STATIC_ROOT setting helped.

Comment: Em... You could mark this as helpful by upvoting it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

***I found that this worked for me. (Development)***
(I chose to name it "zStatic" to keep it at the bottom of the root (project folder), so that it isnt amidst all my apps. Easier to locate.)

***Settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = 'zStatic/'  
STATICFILES_DIRS = (  
BASE_DIR/'zStatic',  
)

INSTALLED_APPS = 
[
...
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
...
]
```

***base.html*** (*base template*)

```
<head>  
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mycss.css' %}"> 
</head>
```